# PHP Splitting a String

Tags: php, split, preg-split

Okay, here is the question. I have a string. This string is a combination of US State Codes

```
$codes = 'ALAKAZARCACOCTDEDCFLGAHIIDILINIAKSKYLAMEMDMAMIMNMSMOMTNENVNHNJNMNYNCNDOHOKORPARISCSDTNTXUTVTVAWAWVWIWY';
```

I need to split the string into two letters, such as "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR" etc.

I can't think of any other SIMPLE function other than `preg_split` but I am not an expert in regular expression.

Can any of you think about any other easy method to split the string ? The other function close to the answer what I can think of is using "substr".  Looking for more options and also preg_split example.

Comment: ex. regex like `'\[A-Z]{2}\'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $codes = 'ALAKAZARCACOCTDEDCFLGAHIIDILINIAKSKYLAMEMDMAMIMNMSMOMTNENVNHNJNMNYNCNDOHOKORPARISCSDTNTXUTVTVAWAWVWIWY';  
    $arr = str_split($codes, 2);
    print_r($arr);

?>
```